# locally disable function inlining

Tags: c++, c

I need to make the compiler to not inline an inlined function.
eg:

I have an inline function **A**.

I have a function **B** that calls **A**.
In **B**, **A** is inlined and this is perfect.

Now I have a function **C** that calls **A** many times.
In **C**, **A** is inlined, and it is not good.

Is it possible to tell the compiler to not inline **A** when it is called from **C** ?

--edit--

The first Idea is to create the function **__declspec(noinline) A1** (that simply calls **A**) and call **A1** instead of **A** in **C**.
But I wondering if there is a more elegant solution ?

**note**
I know that **inline** is only a suggestion, but in my program, I have some unlikely or error cases where the compiler inline functions but should not because in these cases I prefer function calls to reduce code size. I also noticed that the compiler is not always able to make the best choice (in the point of view of the developer)

Comment: Which compiler are you using?  Some of them specify pragmas that allow you to say the function should not be inlined.

Comment: Note that the compiler might already do this for you. At least in C++, the `inline` keyword is just a hint to the compiler, and the compiler can decide not to inline if it considers that as a bad idea.

Comment: how about calling it through a function pointer?

Comment: I agree with you David, But unfortunately in some situations, the compiler is not able to make the best choice.

Comment: Don't mess with that. Generally if you are targeting a small executable compile with `-Os` or similar. If you really, really, think that this is worth looking at, compile with `-S` to produce the assembler of your function and check if things are inlined or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the following solution:

```
template <class F> ALWAYS_INLINE F NOINLINE( F f ) {

  return f;
}
```

It seems that the compiler (MSVC at least) don't inline functions called like this:

```
NOINLINE(my_inline_function)();
```

I think it is similar to the "calling it through a function pointer" solution from *Nick D*

Answer (score 8):

In general, you cannot tell your compiler to inline or not inline a function. This is an internal optimization and even if you declare a function inline, the compiler may chose to not do so.

Some compilers allow you to control inlining to some extent. For instance, GCC has a function attribute *noinline* that prevents it from being inlined.

In your case, I'd try something like this:

```
inline void a() { ... }

void __attribute__((noinline)) wrap_a()
{ a(); }

void b() {  a(); }

void c() { wrap_a(); }
```

Comment: This solution is probably similar to the declspec() idea in your question.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it should be the answer for this question, but I guess the OP was using MSVC.

Answer (score 4):

Inlining is only a suggestion to compiler -- it is quite possible that the function won't be pasted in the second case. I would just trust the compiler and leave it as is.

Comment: True, it is a suggestion, but in my program, I have some some unlikely or error cases, where the compiler inline function but I think it should not.  In these cases I prefer function calls to reduce code size.

Comment: @Soubok This way NickD comment is probably the most generic idea; the other option is to look for complier-specific flags/constructs that enforce or deny pasting.

Answer (score 0):

The most straight forward solution is to put the function code into a separate file.

Comment: Note that I have enabled "Whole program optimization" that may avoid the effect of file separation.

Comment: @Soubok, yes in that case all files are "joined", therefore this indeed won't work.